# CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVCompilerOptimizations.cmake:505 (message): Compiler doesn't support baseline optimization flags

Tags: javascript, python, opencv, cmake

I'm trying to build openCv.js javascript library from opencv source code at this [github repository](https://github.com/opencv/opencv)
I followed instructions at this [official page](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d4/da1/tutorial_js_setup.html)
I installed cmake, python, and Emscripten.
when I run this python command :

```
python ./platforms/js/build_js.py build_js
```

I get the following error :

```
-- Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "2.7.13", but required
is at least "3.4" (found E:/Github projects/emsdk-master/python/2.7.13.1_64bit/p
ython-2.7.13.amd64/python.exe)
-- Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "2.7.13", but required
is at least "3.2" (found E:/Github projects/emsdk-master/python/2.7.13.1_64bit/p
ython-2.7.13.amd64/python.exe)
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVCompilerOptimizations.cmake:505 (message):
Compiler doesn't support baseline optimization flags:
Call Stack (most recent call first):
cmake/OpenCVCompilerOptions.cmake:261 (ocv_compiler_optimization_options)
CMakeLists.txt:554 (include)
```

[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9ZCt.png)

how can I fix this error and build opencv.js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update python version to be at least 3.4